# How to change textformfield position?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Design I want:
[image]

My current design:
[image]

Hello. I want to ask. How to change the position of the textformfield to be closer to the CircleAvatar as in the image of the design I want. I have tried changing the margin and padding of the container but it still doesn't change. I am new to using flutter. Please help. I am attaching my current code.

```
return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      body: _progressBarActive == true
          ? loadingScreen
          : _pageContent == null
              ? Container(
                  margin:
                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 5),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                  child: LayoutBuilder(
                    builder: (context, constraints) => Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.transparent,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 120.0),
                          height: 200 + 70 + 60,
                          child: Stack(
                            clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment(0, -.35),
                                  child: Container(
                                    width: constraints.maxWidth,
                                    height: 3,
                                    color: mainColor,
                                  )),
                              Positioned(
                                top: 40,
                                left: 650,
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    FutureBuilder(
                                      future: _getSignedURL(
                                          widget.patientProfile.avatar),
                                      builder: (BuildContext context,
                                          AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                                        if (snapshot.data == null) {
                                          return Container(
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            child: Container(
                                              width: 200,
                                              height: 200,
                                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                color: Color.fromRGBO(
                                                    255, 255, 255, 0.3),
                                                border: Border.all(
                                                  color: Colors.black12,
                                                  width: 1.0,
                                                ),
                                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                                    Radius.circular(200.0)),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          );
                                        } else {
                                          return CircleAvatar(
                                            radius: 100,
                                            backgroundImage:
                                                NetworkImage(snapshot.data),
                                          );
                                        }
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: double.infinity,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 10),
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 210),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(
                              color: Colors.transparent,
                              width: 1.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Expanded(
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  children: [
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 30,
                                      child: Text(
                                        'First Name',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            fontSize: 16),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 300,
                                      //height: 100,
                                      child: TextFormField(
                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.black),
                                        controller: firstName,
                                        onSaved: (String? value) {
                                          firstName.text = value!;
                                        },
                                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                          hintText: 'First Name',
                                          hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 16),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
 

                               ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
                )
```

I have someone willing to help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The margin on top Container is too big,  `margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 120.0),` use `.only`

```dart
 margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 120.0, bottom: 10),
```

It will here

[image]

Comment: Which one is the margin container?

Comment: LayoutBuilder<Column<Container, I've attached an image

Comment: Glad to help, also you might just relay on padding instead of margin. Another thing  is for others widgets you might use constrains or flexible size like on Row